# TCP Connection slows down after 10.000 packets

Tags: qt, tcp

I am using the QT implementation of the TCP stack to control a robot. We exchange short msgs (<200Byte) and have a round trip time of about 8ms. After maybe 10.000 Packets in each direction, the connection slows down and i have to wait about 1 sec for the answer of my packet. If I restart my program, and reconnect, I again get the 8ms RTT.

For me it sounds like some kind of buffer is filling up but I havn't worked with TCP much, so maybe some one could give me a hint.

Comment: Have you been able to determine if it's your Qt program, or if it's the robot that's causing the delay?

Comment: When you read from a receiving Tcp Connection, are you reading all of the buffer? If not then it's likely that this may be your problem.

Comment: @RobbieE: How would you decide who causes the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the code that you're not showing. Likely the slot that gets executed on `readyRead()` is not emptying the buffer.

1. It is acceptable for the buffer not to be completely empty, say when you're reading complete lines/packets.
2. It is not acceptable for the buffer size to be constantly growing.

At the end of your slot reading slot, check if `bytesAvailable()` is non-zero. It can only be non-zero in case #1. Even then, you should be able to place an upper bound on it - say some small multiple of packet size or maximum line length. If the bound is ever exceeded, you've got a bug in your code.

Comment: I  read all the data available:
    char buffer[socket.bytesAvailable];
    socket.read(buffer, socket.bytesAvailable()); bytesAvailable is 0 afterwards

Comment: @Foo: Then your problem is in the robot. Use wireshark to monitor what's going on the wire. Most likely the reply is coming back with a long delay.

Answer (score -2):

It is just a wild guess, but a common catch by using qt sockets is that you need to delete the socket object by yourself ( for example with "deleteLater()") on error and disconnection.
Example code:

```
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), socket, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

The event loop will then remove the socket the next time it is able to do it.
The QTcpSockets or AbstractSockets don't delete themselfs on close() or on leaving the scope (because then the Signal/Slots won't work).

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: It is related, because it is an often made mistake by using QTcpSocket which causes a memory leak. This would explain why is application repairs itself after a restart. As I said its a guess because he provided no code.. maybe i should have wrote in  a comment instead of an answer.. (similiar problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781140/qtcpsocket-qtcpserver-memory-management-server-crash)